# how can I delete multiple variables without actually typing variables one by one?

Tags: python, filter, global-variables, filtering

I defined a function **filtering()** as following:

```py
def filtering(given_indices, string):
    string = string.replace(" or "," | ").replace(" and "," & ").replace("-","_")
    tag_list = [i.strip("() ") for i in string.replace(" | ","`").replace(" & ","`").split("`")]
    for tag in tag_list:
        variable_name = tag
        globals()[variable_name] = Filter(given_indices, variable_name)
    return eval("({}).indices".format(string))
```

with a well-defined class **Filter** that includes operators & and |. **string** may consist of multiple tags, parentheses, either of the two operators or both. e.g. "china and (mountain or mountains)". The result of running this function is filtered indices, with having as many variables as the **tag**s in **tag_list**.
 What I want to do is to add a code that delete all variables generated as the result of **for tag...globals()...variable_name)** (e.g. **china**, **mountain**, **mountains**), so that none of the variables are left after executing the function **filtering()** and obtaining returned indices. How can I do this?

------------------------------------------------------------------
Providing the entire code below to make things more clear

```py
def wth(given_indices, tag):
    if "_" in tag:
        tag = tag.replace("_", "-")
    if tag.startswith("no_"):
        tag = tag[3:]
        return list(filter(lambda x: not tag in data_taglists[x], given_indices))
        # data_taglists is pre-given 
    else:
        return list(filter(lambda x: tag in data_taglists[x], given_indices))

class Filter:
    def __init__(self, given_indices, tag):
        self.given_indices = given_indices
        self.indices = wth(self.given_indices, tag)
    def __and__(self, other_tag_class):
        obj = Filter(self.given_indices, "")
        obj.indices = list(set(self.indices) & set(other_tag_class.indices))
        obj.indices.sort()
        return obj
    def __or__(self, other_tag_class):
        obj = Filter(self.given_indices, "")
        obj.indices = list(set(self.indices) | set(other_tag_class.indices))
        obj.indices.sort()
        return obj

def filtering(given_indices, string):
    string = string.replace(" or "," | ").replace(" and "," & ").replace("-","_")
    tag_list = [i.strip("() ") for i in string.replace(" | ","`").replace(" & ","`").split("`")]
    for name in tag_list:
        globals()[name] = Filter(given_indices, name)
    return eval("({}).indices".format(string))

# e.g.
data_taglists = [['sky', 'ocean', 'people', 'blue', 'clouds', 'korea'],
['sky', 'mountain', 'tree', 'morning', 'korea'],
['sky', 'tree', 'snow', 'footstep', 'usa'],
['forest', 'tree', 'insect', 'firefly', 'night', 'japan'],
['sky', 'tree', 'insect', 'sunlight', 'usa'],
['sky', 'building', 'people', 'road', 'car', 'china'],
['sky', 'tree', 'person', 'road','china']]

given_indices = range(len(data_taglists))
print(filtering(given_indices, "korea or usa"))
print(filtering(given_indices, "(usa or korea or japan) and (sky and tree) and no_insect)")
a = filtering(given_indices, "korea")
print(filtering(a, "usa")
```

I know it might look horrible cause I merely know the basics of coding. I would appreciate you if you tell me what I can improve in detail.

Comment: This is a huge red flag that your code is not designed well. There is almost never a good reason to create/delete variables dynamically

Comment: Why does your `filtering` function create the global variable to begin with? Just don't create them. There's no need. There is even less of a need for `eval`.

Comment: How can I get fix the code with the same result, then? Could you describe in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete individual names with `del` : del `variable_name`

You can remove any variable by looking up globals() object

```
for name in dir():
    print(name)
    if not name.startswith('_'): # variables starting with an _ are internal variables
        del globals()[name]
```